# How to export .key and .crt from keystore

Tags: java, android, tomcat, ssl

When I was building android app on development machine, I was required to have SSL certificate for app so I generated a keystore with keytool for Tomcat. I extracted the cert from keystore and put it into .bks for using android, and all went well.

Now we have to shift all server-side code to server which required Apache HTTP and Tomcat. Apache HTTP SSL requires .key and .crt files and I cannot find a way to export .key and .crt file from the keystore

Can anyone help with this? I found that you can generate .crt from .pem

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in your-cert.pem -out your-cert.crt
```

But how can i get .key file?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Keytool (available in JDK) allows you to export certificates to a file:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore [keystore] -alias [alias] -file [cert_file]
```

To export regular keys you should use -importkeystore command (surprise):

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore [keystore] -destkeystore [target-keystore] -deststoretype PKCS12
```

Comment: This never works, exporting keys does not work this way

Comment: Do you mind explaining why it does not work for you?

Comment: For apache this is not the way you export. First you need to export key in .p12 format
Then ,export only certs to create .crt files and export only  key or create .key file using openSSL. Doing this gives error , certificate in not valid PEM file.

See,
http://serverfault.com/questions/715827/how-to-generate-key-and-crt-file-from-jks-file-for-httpd-apache-server

Comment: The question was how to export key file. Converting to PEM is already explained in question itself

Comment: Key file is exported in .p12 format but later on it is not clear how to store that to .key file using openSSL

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/66865/130215 this is a more complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just write a script to streamline the process.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Extracts the private key and certificate from a Java keystore and saves them
#
# Ouputs:
#   <keystore>.p12: private key and certificate in PKCS12 format
#   <keystore>.pem: private key and certificate in PEM format
#   <keystore>.crt: certificate only
#   <keystore>.key: private key only

# Usage:
#   jks2pem.sh <keystore>

# Example:
#   jks2pem.sh keystore.jks

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: jks2pem.sh <keystore>.jks"
    exit 1
fi

base_name=$(basename "$1" .jks)
temp_password="changeit"

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore "$1" -srcstoretype jks \
    -destkeystore "$base_name.p12" -deststoretype PKCS12 \
    -deststorepass "$temp_password"

# Export the private key and certificate as a PEM file without a password
openssl pkcs12 -nodes -in "$base_name.p12" -out "$base_name.pem" -passin pass:"$temp_password"

# Export the certificate as a PEM file
openssl pkcs12 -nokeys -in "$base_name.p12" -out "$base_name.crt" -passin pass:"$temp_password"

# Export the private key as a PEM file
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -nodes -in "$base_name.p12" -out "$base_name.key" -passin pass:"$temp_password"
```

Answer (score -4):

You can create new set of key and self signed certificate using the following steps:

1. Creation of key and certificate signing request:

   ```
   openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -out cert.csr -keyout cert.key
   ```
2. Creation of pem

   ```
   openssl x509 -req -signkey cert.key -in cert.csr -out cert.pem
   ```