# Cordova can't build release anymore

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using Cordova v8 with android v7
I can build a debug build without issue but release build now breaks.
I've tried to remove/add android, recreating the project, nothing does it.
I'm using a build.json and it used to work perfectly, and do

```
 cordova build android --release
```

Here is the error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Script 
'D:\myapp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 147

* What went wrong:
Failed to create component for 'dialog' reason: java.awt.HeadlessException
> java.awt.HeadlessException (no error message)
```

How can I fix this??? I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909265/failed-to-create-component-for-dialog-reason-java-awt-headlessexception) without success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is a [Cordova bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13684) so I will answer and close this question.

Answer (score 11):

Although this is closed, I would like to post my workaround, as this costed me about two days to figure out.
My build failed after an update to Cordova, too.

To get it fixed, I defined not only the password in build.json, but also the storePassword field. As my store had no password before, I recreated the store with a password set. As both fields are present in the build.json, the insert password dialog, that causes the exception doesn't show up and the build runs through.

This is my build.json:

```
{
  "android": {
      "release": {
          "keystore": "key.storenew",
          "storePassword": "my_password",
          "alias": "my_alias",
          "password": "my_password",
          "keystoreType":"jks"
      }
  }
}
```

To set a keystore password use the second command from this answer:
[How to export .key and .crt from keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087537/how-to-export-key-and-crt-from-keystore/23087752#23087752)

Comment: But that's the issue, is that you cannot have an empty store password, which is optional...